# Oracle dblink to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, dblink

Can I create a dblink to a SQL Server from Oracle, in the same I would if I was creating a dblink from Oracle to Oracle?
I've tried, but get a message saying -

> connection has closed as partner has disconnected.

Thanks in advance

K

Comment: Creating a database link from Oracle to MS SQL is not as straightforward as creating database links between Oracle and Oracle. You need to install an ODBC driver that is able to connect to MS SQL databases, then configure Oracle Heterogeneous Services with DG4ODBC, then create the database link using that. This is the free version. You can also use Oracle Database Gateway for SQL Server, but that must be licensed just as the Oracle Database itself.

Comment: Check this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134688/creating-a-database-link-from-oracle-to-sql-server